# boost::thread_sleep vs boost::chrono::thread_clock inconsistent

Tags: c++, boost, benchmarking

When I run this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/thread_clock.hpp>

void foo() {
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(500));
}


int main() {
    boost::chrono::thread_clock::time_point start = boost::chrono::thread_clock::now();    
    foo();   
    boost::chrono::thread_clock::time_point stop = boost::chrono::thread_clock::now();    
    std::cout << "duration = " 
              << boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::microseconds>(stop-start).count() 
              << " microsec\n";
}
```

I get the following output:

```
duration = 121 microsec
duration = 121 microsec
duration = 110 microsec
duration = 114 microsec
```

Also when I replace the `500` with a different value, eg `200`, the output is always around `100`. Compiling with `-O3`. Why is the timing not consistent?

PS: I read that `sleep` is deprecated, but when I replace it with

```
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::microseconds(200));
```

the output is in the range of ~20 microseconds.

Comment: What does `thread_clock` measure?

Comment: @PeteBecker [thread_clock class provides access to the real thread wall-clock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.other_clocks.thread_clock_hpp.thread_clock), or was this a rethorical quesiton and I am overlooking something obvious?

Comment: thread_clock measures the actual CPU time spent in the thread. Sleep doesn't increase this number (or at least, it just increases it a little bit).

Comment: When a thread sleeps it isn't using CPU time, so it seems like the "real thread wall-clock" won't show much time used. Look at the system-wide wall clock (`std::chrono::system_clock` or one of the other variants) to see sleep time.

Comment: @PeteBecker I always thought that wall-time / wall-clock measures real time including sleep as opposed to cpu-time. Anyhow, I will try to use `system_clock`

Comment: Yes, "wall-time/wall-clock" measures elapsed time including sleep. But "real **thread** wall-clock" (a word salad) claims to measure "the real CPU-time clock of the calling thread" (another word salad, but maybe refers to CPU time rather than wall-clock time).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I was overlooking something obvious. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.other_clocks.thread_clock_hpp.thread_clock) says:

> thread_clock class provides access to the real thread wall-clock, i.e.
>   the real CPU-time clock of the calling thread.

I thought wall-time is the real time passed, as opposed to the cpu-time that does not include the time a thread is sleeping. Anyhow, to get consistent numbers I had to use `boost::chrono::system_clock` instead.